# How to do multiple comparisons while sorting a dictionary of lists in python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists, `summary`:

```
summary = {
    'Raonic': [2, 0, 11, 122, 16, 139],
    'Halep': [2, 2, 10, 75, 6, 60],
    'Kerber': [2, 0, 7, 68, 7, 71],
    'Wawrinka': [1, 2, 14, 133, 13, 128],
    'Djokovic': [2, 2, 10, 75, 8, 125],
}
```

I wish to print out to the screen (standard output) a summary in decreasing order of ranking, where the ranking is according to the criteria 1-6 in that order (compare item 1 (of the list), and if equal compare item 2 (of the list), if those are equal compare item 3 (of the list). This comparison continues till item 4 of the list in *descending order*.

However the comparison of item 5 and item 6 of the lists must be done in the *ascending order*.

Output:

```
Halep 2 2 10 75 6 60
Djokovic 2 2 10 75 8 125
Raonic 2 0 11 122 16 139
Kerber 2 0 7 68 7 71
Wawrinka 1 2 14 133 13 128
```

My Solution was:

```
for key, value in sorted(summary.items(), key=lambda e: e[1][0], reverse = True):
    print(key, end=' ')
    for v in value:
        print(v, end=' ')
    print()
```

However my solution merely succeeds at sorting on column 1 of the list.

Visit [this site for full question](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2011/assignments/assignment1.txt)

Comment: from the link this looks like a homework question with no prior effort put in to it

Comment: It is an assignment, yes. And I did accomplish everything except how to sort a dictionary using multiple comparisons. I was yet to find a satifactory answer when I posted the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For numeric values, you can negate the value to get the inverse sort. For your sort key, return a sequence of the values that are to be sorted, negating the values that go in the 'opposite' direction:

```
ranked = sorted(
    summary.items(),
    key=lambda kv: kv[1][:4] + [-kv[1][4], -kv[1][5]],
    reverse=True)
```

This produces `(key, value)` tuples in sorted order, as dictionaries are unordered.

For `('Halep', [2, 2, 10, 75, 6, 60])`, the sort key lambda returns `[2, 2, 10, 75, -6, -60]`, ensuring that this is sorted *before* `'Djokovic'` where the sort key is set to `[2, 2, 10, 75, -8, -125]`, because in reversed sort order (`reverse=True`), `-6` is sorted before `-8`. However, any difference in value in the first 4 columns is sorted in the other direction, so anything with `3` or more in the first column will be sorted before `('Halep', [...])`, or anything starting with `2, 3` or higher, etc.

Where values are not numeric and there is no other 'inverse' value option available for the columns, you'd have to sort *twice*. First on the last 2 columns (sorting in ascending order), then on the first 4 columns (in descending, so reversed, order):

```
# non-numeric option
part_sorted = sorted(summary.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][-2:])
ranked = sorted(part_sorted, key=lambda kv: kv[1][:4], reverse=True)
```

This works because Python's sort algorithm (called [*Timsort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)) is *stable*, the relative order of any two inputs for which the sort key is exactly equal is untouched. So any keys *A* and *B*, where only the last on or two columns differ, are given an relative ordering in `part_sorted` that then doesn't change in `ranked` because the `part_sorted` order is untouched. If *A* is sorted after *B* in the first sort then the second sort will leave *A* after *B*.